# pushViewController animates the navigation bar but the new view doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got an iOS app that is doing some crazy stuff... I'll do my best to describe it.

My navigation architecture is as follows:

AppDelegate calls this:

```
tabNavController = [[MainTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tabNavController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

MainTabViewController inherits from `UITabBarController`

Inside MainTabViewController's viewDidLoad, I programmatically load my tabs into an NSMutableArray and assign it to the tabControllers:

```
NSMutableArray *tabs;

StreamViewController *controller = [StreamViewController alloc] initWithNib...];
UINavigationController *navCon = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[tabs addObject:navContorller];

...
self.viewControllers = tabs;
```

My very first tab -- the one that is displayed by default -- inherits from UIViewController. I have a UITableView setup in a XIB as the main view. My class is the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

```
StreamViewController : BaseModuleViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

The table loads and displays fine. When a user clicks a row, I push a new view controller to the stack:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
   ...
   DetailViewController* detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
   ...
}
```

This is where it gets strange. The view controller acts like its going to display, but it doesn't. I see my navigationBar animate -- my buttons shift around, the title changes, and a Back button shows up -- but the view itself does not display. I can even continue to click the table view cells and continually load more and more views, each new one animates the navbar and shows a new back button. I can then hit back X number of times to get "back" to my StreamViewController.

Here's the next kicker. If I navigate to tab #2, then back to tab #1, none of the above happens and the view appears exactly like it should.

Strange - anyone seen this and have an idea of what's going on?

**EDIT**

Here's a YouTube video showing it not working: http://youtu.be/Shces88d6Go

Comment: How is it navigating at all? You said the the controller in the first tab inherits from UIViewController, where is the navigation controller coming from? Is that first tab controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: @rdelmar My bad, I left a step out.. in short, each of the tab items are UINavigationControllers. I'll edit and update

Comment: I can't see anything in the code you posted that would cause this. What did you change and/or add to UITabBarController in your subclass, MainTabViewController?

Comment: I'm  little confused by this: "My very first tab -- the one that is displayed by default -- inherits from UIViewController. I have a UITableViewController setup in a XIB as the main view." Do you mean UITableView (as opposed to UITableViewController), or is there another controller here besides StreamViewController? When I looked at your video, I see a back button with "Stream" on it, so it appears that is not the first controller. Please clarify.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, UITableView. Also, you see "Stream" because the video starts right as I click on a table view cell. Normally, you'd not see the back button with stream, but as soon as I click once, it animates and changes to "Stream"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I was launching a modal window in the viewDidLoad method of my MainTabViewController. This somehow confused the system and was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a navigation controller as your root view controller.

```
tabNavController = [[MainTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabNavController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navCtrl;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: it does the same thing, unfortunately.