# Strange behaviour of UINavigationController when the applications rootViewController is a tabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to push a UIViewController onto a UINavigationController. The NavigationBar changes (i.e. a back-button appears) but the view is not pushed (*).

I have a UITabBarController as my applications RootViewController.

When I switch to another tab and then switches back, the view (*) gets pushed.

I have never seen this behaviour before. My problem is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420427/pushviewcontroller-animates-the-navigation-bar-but-the-new-view-doesnt-show-up), however the methods that solved that issue did not solve mine.

**Initially**

[image]

**After I press the row**

[image]

I understand that this question might be related to issues in AppDelegate, therefore i post the code I use.

Code:

**in AppDelegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"DBModel"];

/* CONTACTS LIST CONTROLLER */
BoonContactListViewController *contactListViewController = [[BoonContactListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *contactListNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contactListViewController];
[contactListNavigationController setValue:[[BoonNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
contactListNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = [NSLocalizedString(@"CONTACTS", nil) capitalizedString];
contactListNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_contacts.png"];


/* INVITATIONS */

BoonInvitationListViewController *invitationListController = [[BoonInvitationListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *invitationNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:invitationListController];
[invitationNavigationController setValue:[[BoonNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
invitationNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = [NSLocalizedString(@"SETTINGS", nil) capitalizedString];
invitationNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_invitations.png"];

/* SETTINGS */
BoonSettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[BoonSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *settingsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController];
[settingsNavigationController setValue:[[BoonNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
settingsNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = [NSLocalizedString(@"SETTINGS", nil) capitalizedString];
settingsNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_settings.png"];



/* TAB BAR */
BoonTabBarViewController *tabBarController = [[BoonTabBarViewController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[contactListNavigationController, invitationNavigationController, settingsNavigationController];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[tabBarController showLogin];
return YES;
}
```

**EDIT:**

In the viewController that i am trying to push, neither `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad` nor `viewDidAppear` is called.

If I use `presentViewController: animated: completion:` I get the preferred behaviour, id rather not though

**EDIT 2**

How I push my new VC

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

BoonContactInfoViewController *contactInfoViewController = [[BoonContactInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"NAV %@", self.navigationController);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:contactInfoViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT 3**
It is only the initial tab that cannot push ... if i swap places of the first and second tab, i can push a view controller using in the way i do above.

**EDIT 4** 
It works if i (in my tabBarController) calls

```
self.selectedIndex = 1;
self.selectedIndex = 0;
```

**EDIT 5**

```
- (void)showLogin
{

if([BoonUserHandler getLogin].length > 0 && [BoonUserHandler getPassword].length > 0){
    return;
}
BoonWelcomeViewController *welcomeWC = [[BoonWelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *welcomeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeWC];
[welcomeNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];


[self presentViewController:welcomeNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue may be in BoonContactListViewController code. What is the way you push new screen after user presses the cell?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is getting called because you force view to load by `[contactInfoViewController view];` line. Why you call it? Have you overridden `[BoonContactInfoViewController loadView]` ?

Comment: you are correct, now nothing is called.., I had forgot that line there for debug purposes. Updated question.

Comment: thanks, could you please provide the code of `showLogin` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56698/discussion-between-alex-peda-and-eyeball).

Comment: Have you implemented all the methods mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12 ?

Answer (score 1):

What version of iOS are you developing for?

I'd first ask why you're hacking in a nav bar using:

```
[settingsNavigationController setValue:[[BoonNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

rather than the iOS5+ `UINavigationController` method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass
```

But my overall suggestion would be to **remove all this code and use a storyboard**. This looks like the perfect opportunity.

Comment: iOS 7+.
I really do not like storyboards. I prefer to do things programmatically and use xibs for basic layout. The method you provided is now used instead of the setValue: forKeyPath:
..+1 for the supplementary method though

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting wrong Navigation controller to push that's why it showing this problem..

> You have to fetch right navigation controller from tab controller

```
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

just change tab controller selected index